# What's Java's equivalent of .Net's Interlocked class?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, interlocked

How do I modify an int atomically and thread-safely in Java?

Atomically increment, test & set, etc...?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [AtomicInteger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: Which is fine if all you need is the limited set of operations it provides. The "etc" in the question suggests more flexibility.

Comment: Does it ? If he's looking for more, he should be more explicit. AtomicInteger seems to be the right answer in the meantime

Comment: Also have a look at the other classes in the java.util.concurrent package. They can be helpful for the "etc"-stuff

Answer (score 1):

Thread safety can be achieved via synchronized functions.
Wrap your int (or such data) in a class which provides the required functionalities via synchronized methods, e.g.

```
public class X
{
  protected int x;
  public synchronized void set( int value )
  {
    x = value;
  }
}
```

You can also use classes from the [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package, e.g. AtomicInteger or AtomicIntegerArray

### Why this answer won't work

I just wanted to be sure to point out exactly what is wrong with this answer, in case anyone thinks that `synchronized` can be used to solve thread race effects.

```
| Thread A      | Thread B         | 
|---------------|------------------|
| read x (x=4)  |                  |
|               | read x (x=4)     |
| Calculate 4+1 |                  |
| EAX ← 5       |                  |
|               | Calculate 4+1    |
|               | EAX ← 5          |
| Start sync    |                  |
| {             | Start sync       |
| { x ← 5       |    wait          |
| {             |    wait          |
| End sync      |    wait          |
|               | {                | 
|               | { x ← 5          |
|               | {                | 
|               | End sync         |
```

The end result of the operations:

```
x = 4;
x += 1;
x += 1;
```

is that **x = 5** rather than 6.

The same issue exists with the `volatile` keyword. The `volatile` keyword doesn't save you from thread effects. The volatile keyword only ensures that

- caches are flushed before a variable is read
- caches are flushed after a value is written

Strictly speaking, `volatile` ensures that memory operations are not reordered around a volatile variable. Which means you still suffer from the:

- read from x
- write to x

problem.

Comment: Synchronized is pretty heavy weight and wouldn't really serve as an effective replacement for Interlocked. People use Interlocked because it's fast and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static AtomicInteger at = new AtomicInteger();

public void run() {
    at.set(7);
    int i = at.incrementAndGet();
```